# How do i pass php variable inside a row cell to a $_SESSION variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
echo "<form method='post'>
            <tr id='myrow'>
              <td>$id</td>
              <td>$subject</td>
              <td>$department</td>
              <td>$categoryview</td>
              <td>$status</td>
              <td><input type='submit' name='assign' value='Assign me'></td>
            </tr>
          </form>";
    
    if(isset($_POST["assign"])){
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              var Row = document.getElementById('myrow');
              var Cells = Row.getElementByTagName('td');
            </script>";
    }
```

I echo a table inside a form which loops it's rows taking mysql database values passing it to the shown php variables. What i want is that when user clicks on the button (Assign me) the value of `$id` will be passed to a `$_SESSION` variable so i will use that variable in another webpage. What do i need to edit in my code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an action with the php page url you want to redirect to, so for exemple `<form method='post' action='http://localhost/test-site/next.php'>`

You have to use actual input in your table cell if you want the form to natively send the data, so for exemple : `<td><input name="id" value="<?php echo($id); ?>"/></td>`

Next on localhost/test-site/next.php you can access the data in your php with `$theId = $_POST["id"];` and keep it in session with `$_SESSION["id"] = $theId;`

Comment: Thank you very much it worker for me, but problem is that the user can type in the id cell. How do i fix that?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :) You can add disabled to your input <input name="id" value="myValue" disabled /> It will disable the posibility for the user to change input value. Stay safe :)

Comment: I used readonly instead because disable attribute undone the id variable. But thank you very much as you solved the major problem for me. :)

Comment: That was smarter to use readonly indeed in your case, nice job :)